# ratio of second derivatives

Tags: calculus

I have 2 variables (*a* & *b*) that are related by a polynomial expression as follows
$$b = p_1a^3+p_2a^2+p_3a$$
I can easily calculate derivates of *b* with respect to *a* like
$$\frac{db}{da}=3p_1a^2+2p_2a+p_3$$
$$ \frac{d^2b}{da^2}=..., \mbox{etc.}$$
But what I am looking for is the ratio of the second derivatives ($\dfrac{d^2b}{d^2a}$).  I have back calculated the answer & know it has the following form
$$\frac{d^2b}{d^2a}=15p_1a^2+6p_2a+p_3$$
But haven't been able to derive it.  Can anyone help?  Thanks.

***Update:***
I don't think I explained the problem in sufficient detail.  I am working on a non-linear control problem.  *a & b* are angles that are related by a polynomial.  I need to be able to convert instantaneous angles, angular velocities & angular accelerations between the 2 related angles.  So angles are straight forward, you just plug into the first equation.  For velocities, I use the equation above for $db/da(a)$ times the velocity or $$db/dt = (db/da)(da/dt)$$  The problem is converting the instantaneous acceleration of one angle to the acceleration of the other.  I need something of the form $d^2 b/d^2 a$ to multiply by the acceleration of *a* to get the acceleration of *b* or
$$d^2 b/dt^2=(d^2 b/d^2 a)(d^2 a/dt^2)$$  I know the equation has the form shown above because I back calculated it in Matlab, but  can't derive it. Hope that makes more sense.

Comment: Do not write the ratio of the second derivatives as $d^2b/d^2a$.  That is nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

Using the implicit differentiation we have
\begin{align*}
b & = p_1 a^3 + p_2 a^2 + p_3 \\
\frac{d}{db}b & = \frac{d}{db} \big(p_1 a^3 + p_2 a^2 + p_3 \big)\\
1 & = p_1 3a^2 \frac{da}{db} + p_2 2a \frac{da}{db}\\
1 & = \frac{da}{db} (p_1 3a^2  + p_2 2a )\\
\frac{1}{p_1 3a^2  + p_2 2a } & = \frac{da}{db}\\
\end{align*}
If you take another derivative you are going to have
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{p_1 3a^2  + p_2 2a } & = \frac{da}{db}\\
\frac{d}{db} \Big( \frac{1}{p_1 3a^2  + p_2 2a } \Big) & = \frac{d}{db} \Big(\frac{da}{db}\Big)\\
\frac{d}{db} \big(p_1 3a^2  + p_2 2a \big)^{-1} & = \frac{d^2a}{db^2}\\
\big(p_1 3a^2  + p_2 2a \big)^{-2} \frac{d}{db}\big(p_1 3a^2  + p_2 2a \big)& = \frac{d^2a}{db^2}\\
\big(3p_1 a^2  + 2p_2 a \big)^{-2} \big(6p_1 a\frac{da}{db}  + 2p_2 \frac{da}{db}\big)& = \frac{d^2a}{db^2}\\
\big(3p_1 a^2  + 2p_2 a \big)^{-2} \big(6p_1 a  + 2p_2\big) \frac{1}{3p_1a^2  + 2p_2a } & = \frac{d^2a}{db^2}\\
\frac{6p_1 a  + 2p_2}{(3p_1a^2  + 2p_2a)^3 } & = \frac{d^2a}{db^2}\\
\end{align*}

On the other hand you already know $\dfrac{d^2b}{da^2}=6p_1a+2p_2$. If you take the ratio you are going to have.
\begin{align*}
\frac{d^2b}{da^2}\Big/\frac{d^2a}{db^2} = (3p_1a^2  + 2p_2a)^3
\end{align*}
Is it what you mean by the ratio of the second derivatives?

Comment: The question asks for the ratio of the second derivatives.

Comment: @JoeyZou Did I calculate the wrong expression? What is the ratio of the second derivatives?

Comment: When I commented only the first half of your current answer was up. I'm not quite sure what the OP meant by "ratio of second derivatives"; I just wanted to point out that what you had written at the time involved no second derivatives.

Comment: Please see update above.  Hopefully it helps explain my problem.  Thanks.